# how to import a button from one class to another in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

#### Button.js

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Button} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export default function Btn (bgColor, textColor, btnLabel) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        borderRadius: 100,
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 250
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: textColor, fontSize: 22, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        {btnLabel}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

#### Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Background from './Background';
import Btn from './Btn';
import { darkGreen } from './Constants';
// create a component
export default function Home (){
    return (
        <Background>
            <View style= {{ marginHorizontal: 40, marginVertical: 100}}>
           <Btn bgColor={darkGreen} textColor='white' btnLabel="Login"/>
            </View>
            
        </Background>
        
    );
};

// define your styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: can you please share some error so we can resolve easily

Comment: try importing it like:
import {Btn} from './Btn';

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

You can simply call Button component as function like below

```
<Background>
  <View style= {{ marginHorizontal: 40, marginVertical: 100}}>
    {Btn(darkGreen,'white',"Login")}
  </View>
</Background>
```

**Method 2**

You can initialize Button component as like below

```
export default function Btn ({bgColor, textColor, btnLabel}) {
   ...
}
```

note: When you are not calling a component like a function then you need to destructure the props like above